# FFTW for poisson equation in 3D with all Neumman boundary conditions

Tags: c++, fftw, poisson

I am trying to solve Poisson equation in 3D with all Neumman boundary condition by using FFTW library. 
The equation is wirtten as following d^STR/dx^2+d^STR/dy^2+d^2STR/dz^2=-VORTG.
In my opinion, steps to calculate out2 is correct. However, i am not sure the step to calculate STR. 
Could you please give me some advice?
Thank you so much.

```
    void poisson3d(vector<vector<vector<double> > > &STR, vector<vector<vector<double> > > &VORTG)
{
    double pi = 3.141592653589793;
    double XMIN=-2.0;
    double XMAX=2.0;
    double YMIN=-2.0;
    double YMAX=2.0;
    double ZMIN=-2.0;
    double ZMAX=2.0;
    double dd=(XMAX-XMIN)*(YMAX-YMIN)*(ZMAX-ZMIN)/pi/pi/pi;

    std::vector<double> in1(N*N*N,0.0);
    std::vector<double> in2(N*N*N,0.0);
    std::vector<double> out1(N*N*N,0.0);
    std::vector<double> out2(N*N*N,0.0);

    fftw_plan p, q;
    int i,j,k;
    p = fftw_plan_r2r_3d(N, N, N, in1.data(), out1.data(), FFTW_REDFT00 ,FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    q = fftw_plan_r2r_3d(N, N, N, in2.data(), out2.data(), FFTW_REDFT00 ,FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_REDFT00, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    int l=-1;double max=0;
    for (i = 0;i <N;i++)        
        for (j = 0;j<N;j++)
            for (k=0;k<N;k++){ 
                l=l+1;
            in1[l]= VORTG[i][j][k];

            }

    fftw_execute(p);

    l=-1;
    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++){   // f = g / ( kx² + ky² )  
        for( j = 0; j < N; j++){
            for (k=0; k<N; k++){
                l=l+1;
            double fact=0;
            in2[l]=0;

            if(2*i<N){
                fact=((double)i*i);
            }else{
                fact=((double)(N-i)*(N-i));
            }
            if(2*j<N){
                fact+=((double)j*j);
            }else{
                fact+=((double)(N-j)*(N-j));
            }
                if(2*k<N){
                    fact+=((double)k*k);
                }else{
                    fact+=((double)(N-k)*(N-k));
                }

            if(fact!=0){
                in2[l] = out1[l]/fact;
            }else{
                in2[l] = 0.0;
            }

            }
        }
    }

    fftw_execute(q);

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for( j = 0; j < N; j++){
            for (k=0;k<N;k++){
                STR[i][j][k]= dd*out2[l]/((double)2.0*(N-1))/((double)2.0*(N-1))/((double)2.0*(N-1)); 
            }
        }
    }

    fftw_destroy_plan(p); fftw_destroy_plan(q); fftw_cleanup();

}
```

Comment: @Paul R:  could you please give me advice?

Comment: @francis: could you please give me advice?

Answer (score 0):

It quite complicated both physically and mathematically, but still many of the usual C++ debug techniques are still valid.

For starters, there are many simple boundary conditions which allow an exact solution (an all-zero `VORTG` must produce a constant `STR`). Have you checked whether all intermediate values have the expected values for such simple inputs? For somewhat more complicated boundary conditions, you may not be able to come up with exact values for the various intermediates, but you may still be able to check that the signs are right. And finally, you may not know an exact solution for some boundary condition, but you might be able to validate that physical symmetries are adhered to. If you can mirror your boundary conditions, the results should also be mirrored. Are they?

Comment: I have checked another problem with exact solution, i can control it but in my real case, i cannot control it.VORTG has some non-zero values in center of computational domain, anothe value is equal to zeros. My computational domain like a cube with 6 surfaces having zeros Neumman boundary condition. Therefore, i use FFTW_REDFT00. I have already tried with the same problem in 2D and it worked correctly but in 3D it works wrong. My result may be not mirror but boundary is required satisfying. Any more  your advice is  my pleasure and honor. Thank you so much.

Comment: According to MSalters, if VORTG is all zeros, STR is given all constant value. However, VORTG has some value (not equal to zeros) in the middle of computational domain, STR is till all constant value. Why does it happen? I used finite different method for solving this equation, i got value of STR being not constant. Please give me advice if you have ideal.Thank you so much.

Comment: @Luc: I don't understand your comments. Have you actually tried calling your function with an all-zero VORTG? What was the actual result? Is my hunch correct that mathematically, STR should have a single constant value?

Comment: I have already tried with all-zero VORTG and got all zeros constant STR. I am sorry for my unclear comment. This is one subroutine in my program and it take a lot of time to solve my problem. Therefore,i need to add fftw this equation. VORTG is input value from one txt file with some value which is not equal to zero and i need to get STR by solving this equation. But when i run my program, STR is all zero even VORTG is not all zero. I dont know where i get mistake. I would like to post file tex and program in here but i dont know  how can i post it?

Comment: @ MSalters: VORTG is vector in 3D with NxNxN like a cube and have some value which are not equal to zero in middle of cube.if is it possible, please give me your email address, i will send txt file  to you. My email address is mr.nguyenvanluc@gmail.com thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not enough of an expert, sorry. You do have a slow but working algorithm? That gives you another option to debug your FFTW-based algorithm. Can you figure out the reason for the different outputs for a simple single input?

Comment: @ MSalters: Thank you so much for your help. Yes, my program is so slow by using finite different method(FDM) to solve poisson equation. It should be a single output for single input like using FDM. But when i compare result of two methods (FDM and FFT) which give really difference.